# How to let composer automatically resolve conflicts that are not real conflicts?

Tags: composer-php

I'm regularly told by composer that it can't install some kind of package, because it(s dependencies) conflict with something that I already have installed. Often I can't make heads or tails of the conflict, but when it happened again today I looked into it and I saw that there was no real conflict at all.

I wanted to install a package and composer said that the package I wanted depends on `doctrine/inflector` at version `1.4` or higher, but that I already have `doctrine/inflector` installed and locked at `1.3.1`.

I looked into it, and I never required `doctrine/inflector` explicitly. So it's not a direct dependency of my app, but instead it was installed as a dependency of two of my dependencies. Those two dependencies said they needed `doctrine/inflector` at versions `^1.2` and `^1.0` respectively. (I found that information in my `composer.lock` file.)

So now I don't see why composer is making a fuss. Yes composer chose to install `doctrine/inflector` at `1.3.1` in the past to meet the requirements, but there should be no conflict whatsoever if composer just updates the `1.3.1` version it installed in the past to `1.4.1`. But it doesn't do that and instead complains about a conflict.

I now solved the conflict manually by running these commands:

```
$ composer require doctrine/inflector:1.4.1
$ composer require illuminate/support
$ composer remove doctrine/inflector
```

I used `doctrine remove`, because I don't want to have `doctrine/inflector` in my `composer.json`.

So sure, this worked, but is there a way to configure composer such that it tries to solve these conflicts on its own? Because I'm sure there are more complicated scenarios where I wouldn't be able to figure out what to do, but composer possibly could if it would just try.

I did some searching on this site and found that `composer update` could've helped me maybe, but then I'm still curious to know if there's a better alternative. You see I'm looking for a method where *I* don't need to know which packages need updating (and where I don't need to necessarily update all my packages either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve with `composer require` this using these flags:

```sh
$ composer require --help | grep update-with
      --update-with-dependencies      Allows inherited dependencies to be updated, except those that are root requirements.
      --update-with-all-dependencies  Allows all inherited dependencies to be updated, including those that are root requirements.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly the same problem. This seems to be a bad behavior of composer 1.

Switching to composer 2 solves the issue, the option --update-with-all-dependencies (-W) do it's job !

Otherwise, with composer 1 the only solution seems to be the one you did : update manually dependencies, sub-dependencies, sub-sub-... and remove them in composer.json at the end.